# Small data activity when plug USB drive

Tags: usb, network-monitoring, user-data

First of all I am not very advance linux user. Here is the situation : 
When I plug any USB flash drive then it sends about 156 - 300 bytes of data which I have seen at System Monitor. It also happens when I remove the same USB. Also its not one time, each time I insert same USB it send data again.

My ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS, Its has latest update applied and set all the diagnostic data off.

My question is what is the reason for that ?

Comment: Usually that means the system is interrogating the new hardware: "What are you?"

Comment: If I use the same USB over and over again it does the same behavior.

Comment: Of course it does. YOU know that it's the same drive, and that nothing has changed. The system does not. It interrogates ALL hardware plugged in EVERY time. To NOT do so would be a bug.

Comment: You should watch `sudo journalctl -f` as you plug in the USB stick.

Comment: What sort of "data activity" is meant here? Perhaps the question meant network data activity, which would indeed be mysterious. I also get some activity on my ethernet connection whenever I plug in a USB flash drive. Why?